# How do I identify the row number in a For / Select / Loop

Tags: json, oracle, for-loop, select

I have a section of code from an Oracle procedure.  This parts works well as it is:

```
for r in (select * from json_table
            (l_resp, '$.items[0].volumeInfo.authors[*]' 
                columns author varchar2(256) path '$'
            )
          ) 
    loop  
        dbms_output.put_line('The value of Author ' ||  ' is: ' || r.author);  
    end loop r;
```

What I'd like to do is get the row number that is currently being processed.  Something like a ROWNUM for the row "r".
I'd like to adjust the dbms_output line to look something like:

```
dbms_output.put_line('The value of Author ' || r.rownum || ' is: ' || r.author);
```

But the r.rownum doesn't work.  How do I reference something like "r.rownum"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way.

```
For rowz in 
    (select rownum rn, j_auth_tab.*
        from json_table(l_resp, '$.items[0].volumeInfo.authors[*]' 
                        columns author varchar2(512) path '$') j_auth_tab) 
Loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Rownum: ' || rowz.rn || ' Author: ' || rowz.author);
End loop rowz;
```

That solved my problem.